# What is the best way to find circular dependencies in a directed graph data structure?

Tags: database, algorithm, amazon-dynamodb, graph-databases

I have a list of processes and the relations between them stored in a single table (currently in AWS DynamoDB). Additional information associated with the relation like the resource used is also stored.

**Processes table**

```
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|   Caller_ID  |   Callee_ID  |   Resources  |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      P1      |      P2      |      10%     |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      P2      |      P1      |      20%     |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      P3      |      P4      |      15%     |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      P3      |      P1      |      10%     |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      P3      |      P4      |      10%     |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      P4      |      P1      |      10%     |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      ...     |      ...     |      ...     |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|
```

**More info**

- One process can call multiple processes (between 1 and 200+)
- One process can call the same process multiple times
- Number of rows: 10.000 to 1.000.000+

**Goal**

For a given process, I want to find all the circular dependencies (between 4 processes maximum) the given process is included in. Then I need the information of the nodes and the relations included in the circle to do some calculations (on the resources)

For example, result (given P1) would be:

- P1 => P2 => P1 (P1 is calling P2 and P2 is calling P1)
- P1 => P2 => P3 => P1
- P2 => P3 => P4 => P1 => P2

**Questions**

1) Would it be possible to keep the current database structure to achieve this in a cost-effective and performant way? (fetching the nodes and relations and then applying an algorythm). This might not be cost-effective due the high number of queries needed to find all the relations.

2) Would it be possible to do it with DynamoDB and a different table structure?

3) Would a graph database solve this issue? Is it the best way to solve this? Any suggestion on which database to use?

4) Do you suggest a completely different approach?

Comment: Graph queries will benefit from a GraphDB. Check out Amazon Neptune, for example.

Comment: I'd say the queries you provided above are fairly common in graph databases. A three-degree forward or reverse path can solve your problems perfectly. I am sure most graph databases out there can do that for you. For example, you can use Neo4j's `MATCH` or `expand` to search for forward or reverse paths. Or you can use the `GO` statement in Nebula Graph to achieve that.